# Configure environment/path to run python scripts from terminale. For Mac

Tags: python, bash, macos

I found that when I run my scripts from environment - everything is OK.

But, when I try to run them from bash  - I receive different errors with import modules. (ModuleNotFoundError, ImportError)

I didn't set the environment at all, so, please, tell me, what I should configure to succeed with it.

I use python 3.7

Received the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "main.py", line 1, in <module> from package_3.file3 import * 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_3'
```

The structure is:

```
package_1
   file1.py
package_2
   file2.py
package_3
   file3.py
package_4
   file4.py
```

Comment: Could you provide some more details? What version of python are you using (in what you refer to as 'the environment')? What errors are you getting? also, run 'which python' in the shell, and provide the results.

Comment: and when you run 'which python' - what do you get?

Comment: /usr/bin/python

Comment: To help, one really needs to see ***exactly*** what you're seeing. What command do you run when you get this error? What's the current directory? What's the exact file structure? You're getting a message about package_suits, but your file structure doesn't contain any such file or directory.

Comment: I change directory to mine and run command: python3 package_4/file4.py

Answer (score 1):

What happens is, probably, that your working environment is python3, and when you run things in the shell, it's using python2. To solve it, run your script with `python3` in the shell, as in:

```
python3 my_script.py
```

Comment: Exactly in this way I tried, looks like it does not see all imported packages and modules.

Comment: what do you see when you run "python3 --version " and "which -a python3" ?

Comment: Python 3.7.7,


/usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: And what version do you use in the environment where it does work? (what do mean by 'environment', by the way)?

Comment: The same version, python 3.7.

I mean, run/debug configuration, but not sure, I am new in Python, so maybe, it does not matter.

Comment: When you run this in your environment, what do you get: import sys; print(sys.version_info)

Comment: and another thing to check - run "print(sys.argv[0])" in your environment.

Comment: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=7, releaselevel='final', serial=0)


/Users/user_name/PycharmProjects/project_name/main.py

Comment: so you're using PyCharm. Which Python interpreter is configured there (see this page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)?

Comment: I configured it by myself to python 3.7.

Comment: Found now, that when i run something without packages (only .py files) - everything is ok.

Maybe, I made mistake with packages structure, so it does not see them?

Comment: So pyCharm is configured to use /usr/local/bin/python3? The exact same one you're calling from the command line?

Comment: The packages that don't load - are they your packages, or something else? Could you please provide the exact error message you're seeing?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from package_suits.suits import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_suits'

Comment: Pckages are mine, it is the structure.

Comment: So the issue is not with python. It's with the directory you're running the code from, and with the potential lack of PYTHONPATH. Could you please add the tree structure of your code to the question, and also the exact error message you're seeing?

Comment: Added all the issues.